# PDF file search in 'React Native'

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

My objective is to search all PDF files in a android device in a fastest way. I am using `rn-fetch-blob`,
using `RNFetchBlob.fs.lstat` function in a recursive way is allowing me to get the list of all PDF files. But, its taking very long time almost 1-2 minutes.
Can anyone suggest me a better faster way to search all PDF files in android device.

Comment: I would implement something really similar to the react-native-get-music-files. But for pdf files. It uses the mediastore file API for android, and I guess something equivalent for iOS.

Comment: any solution for this.